# Is there any possibility to solve Exception in thread "main" scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing?

Tags: notimplementedexception

Im using a code name watrworks to extract text from pdf but after all i have done i get this error

```
text-works --input in.pdf --output-file output.json

Exception in thread "main" scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
    at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:288)
    at edu.umass.cs.iesl.watr.apps.ProcessPipelineSteps$.$anonfun$markUnextractedProcessables$2(AppShared.scala:395)
    at fs2.Chunk$Singleton.map(Chunk.scala:489)
    at fs2.internal.Algebra$$anon$1.apply(Algebra.scala:68)
    at fs2.internal.Algebra$$anon$1.apply(Algebra.scala:66)
    at fs2.internal.FreeC$Eval.$anonfun$translate$3(FreeC.scala:179)
    at fs2.internal.FreeC$.$anonfun$suspend$1(FreeC.scala:193)
    at fs2.internal.FreeC.$anonfun$flatMap$1(FreeC.scala:33)
...
```

Comment: What's happening at `AppShared.scala:395`?